# How can I have a mouseover event fire for a child element if the parent element has a mouseover too?

Tags: jquery, html-table, hover, mouseevent, mouseover

I have a "help" area on my page and anytime the user hovers over a table the help information should be updated.  The problem is within the table I have a check box in 1 cell of each row, and when the user hovers over that checkbox I want the mouseover event of the checkbox to override the table event and for the checkbox help to be displayed.  Currently the table mouseover works fine but nothing happens when I mouse over the checkbox.

```
<table class="myTable">
   <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<div class="myHelpMenu"></div>


$('.myCheckbox').mouseover(function() {
    $('.myHelpMenu').html("this is my checkbox help");
});

$('.myTable').mouseover(function() {
   $('.myHelpMenu').html("this is my tables help");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/esesov/1/edit)**</kbd>

This is a nice way to detect using `mouseover` the current `target` element that is hovered, than using pure JS to retrieve the `.tagName` you can create a *messages list* object and retrieve the desired one.

```
$('.myTable').mouseover(function( e ) {

  var tag = e.target.tagName;

  var messages = {
    "INPUT" : "this is my checkbox help",
    "TABLE" : "this is my tables help"
  };

  $('.myHelpMenu').text( messages[tag] );

});
```

---

If you want to clear your info message do like:

```
$('.myTable').on('mouseover mouseleave',function( e ) {

  var tag = e.target.tagName;

  var messages = {
    "INPUT" : "this is my checkbox help",
    "TABLE" : "this is my tables help"
  };

  $('.myHelpMenu').text( messages[tag] );

  if(e.type=='mouseleave')
    $('.myHelpMenu').empty();

});
```

Comment: @Mercurybullet :) thanks hahaha but if it's just for the button "sweetness" you can remove the +1 :) (P.S you're free to use and abuse :D )

Comment: Have to admit, that was a pretty sweet livedemo. Almost feel guilty you went to all that trouble just to answer this. I'm quickly reminded why I love this site!

Comment: @JSilva :) if it was not for this site, I'd probably never start doing programming in my life (or I would surely quit soon for sure :D ). Thank you for reminding me on that!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to have the mouseover for the the checkbox stop propagation up to the table?

If so, this should do it.

```
$('.myCheckbox').mouseover(function(e) {
    $('.myHelpMenu').html("this is my checkbox help");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it helped solve answer your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the `mouseover` for the table is for the whole area, just call `mouseenter` instead. You could then add a `mouseout` to reupdate after they leave the table.

Comment: but the challenge is the input checkbox is within the table, so how would I trigger the mouseout for the table?

Comment: Lots of ways but Mercurybullet has the best solution here. Very good indeed.